# MYSQL & Java Applet

Tags: java, jdbc, applet

I am currently changing a java desktop application over to a java applet. Everything is working fine, but as soon as the applet attempts to make a mysql database call, it does not work. The code in the desktop application is fine, but as soon as its called from the application its not working.

Do any changes need to be made to the code because it is being called from an applet rather then a desktop application using JDBC?

Thanks

~ Kyle G

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'doesn't work' ? Exceptions etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're probably trying to talk to a server other than the one serving your applet ? See [this](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/applet/security/security.html) for applet security restrictions.

Comment: Thats it!. Just ran them from the same server and problem was solved. Thanks :)

Comment: Good. It's probably worth providing more info re. the error in future, since the above was a bit of an informed guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC in the applet can not connect to the other server port : security restrictions like they can not read file on your desktop